# Acceleration of masses suspended from accelerating pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, string

[image: Here is the picture]

In this problem there are these equations

[image: Here are the equations]

Assume 2A is greater than g and second mass, and second mass is greater than first one. Then the second mass will go upwards. Because the equation for second mass' acceleration will be positive.(like M1=1kg M2=2kg A=20N/kg).

Can it really happen? Is this equation physically true? As far as the 2nd mass is larger, how can it be possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Since the 2nd block is lower it may work somewhat like siphoning fuel. The fuel weighs the same at both ends. The fuel instead being connected by vacuum your model is connected by a line and the center of gravity is lower on the 2nd block and low enough to lift the heavier weight.

Comment: Google Elevator physics

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Your question is badly written. eg You say "as the 1st mass is larger" but in the data you give M2 is larger than M1.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you for your comment, it was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite evident: $A$ is an **acceleration** upwards.

You're getting that the second mass accelerates upwards, but the thing is wether it raises **faster or slower** than the lighter mass.

If you see, the only difference between $\ddot{y}_1$ and $\ddot{y}_2$ is the substraction upside. Since you're substracting a lower quantity in (1), acceleration 1 is greater than acceleration 2.

This is obvious because $2A>g$, according to what you're saying, then it is obvious that it "wants to fall" but $A$ doesn't let it go down.

In short, $M_2$ goes down with respect to the pulley, but still upwards with respect to the ground, where you have your reference frame.

Comment: Well I didn't do the full exercise. It's you who has to try. Just try to redo the problem setting the RF in teh pulley, but being aware that it's a non-inertial frame, so you must add a ficticious force. Account being taken of that, check if it makes sense.